# how to apply css to a link within a particular div only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my situation. I have 3 divs on my website. There is a button in each of divs. Here is my codes :

```
<div id="gg1">
  <a class="btn">
</div>
<div id="gg2">
  <a class="btn">
</div>
<div id="gg3">
  <a class="btn">
</div>
```

May I know how to apply css style to 1 button only without effect on other 2 buttons Css or Jquery? Note that I cannot change the class and id of the buttons.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors):

```
#gg1 a.btn {
    /* styles here affect only a.btn elements within #gg1 */
}
```